# Using jQuery latest version with Drupal with require.js AMD

Tags: jquery, drupal, requirejs, amd

I am using Drupal and want to get latest jQuery version. From what I read there are several crucial modules that have conflicts with the latest versions. I tried a Drupal module called "jQuery update" but the version is 1.5.2....
One solution I thought about is using require.js AMD in order to load the latest version for use in my module (javascript module, not Drupal module). My concern is with conflicts regarding the two jQuery versions. My module is closed and can be loaded itself with require.js AMD. An example for it can be found 
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/yhXrj/8/) or:

```
(function($) {

$(function() {
    require.config({
        paths: {
            "jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min"
        }
    });


    // Now that we have configured a named alias for the jQuery
    // library, let's try to load it using the named module.
    require([
        "jquery"
        ], function($jq182) {


        var MyModule = (function($jq182) {
            return {
                init: function() {
                    // Log the callback parameter.
                    console.log("$jq182.fn.jquery:", $jq182.fn.jquery);
                }
            };

        }($jq182));


        MyModule.init();
    });

});

}(jQuery));​
```

(notice that the old version is referenced in the old fasion way (to demonstrate Drupal's reference), and the new jQuery reference is loaded with require.js)

Thanks!!

Comment: [This](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28820/how-do-i-update-jquery-to-the-latest-version-i-can-download) might be useful

Comment: The latest jQuery Update dev version bumps to jQuery 1.8 and also replaces several Drupal core's javascript to fix incompatibilities.